Use of @setup seems to suppress comments in actual scenario outine within the karate report
When running the following code, the comments in the scenario outline are not shown in the karate report.  Is this an expected result of using setup or a bug?
Looking at the image below, we were expecting the following comments line in the report.

# printing initial name value
# printing initial replaceVar value

Feature: scenario outline using a dynamic generator function
Background:
  # setting url
    * url 'https://www.google.com'

    * def replacementVar = 'this was a replaced variable'

  @setup
  Scenario: setup of data
  # creating json data and casting as string for replacement
    * def testGenerator = [{ name: 'test replaceVar', replaceVar: '<replaceVar>'},{ name: 'test replaceVar', replaceVar: '<replaceString>' }]
    * print 'testGenerator-initial-',testGenerator

  # printing current generated data value
    * string testGenerator = testGenerator
    * print 'testGenerator-string-',testGenerator

  # replacing data in generated data
    * replace testGenerator
    | token         | value             |
    | replaceVar    | 'replacementVar'  |
    | replaceString | 'replaced String' |

  # converting generated data back to json object for use in scenario
    * json testGenerator = testGenerator

  # printing updated generated data value
    * print 'testGenerator-json-',testGenerator

  Scenario Outline: test name: ${name}
  # printing initial name value
    * print 'name-',name
  # printing initial replaceVar value
    * print 'replaceVar-',replaceVar

    Examples:
    | karate.setup().testGenerator |



quite likely a bug, code contributions welcome

Would you like me to submit the bug ticket?  Is the info above enough or do you require more?

comment replied to, but no follow-up https://stackoverflow.com/users/143475/peter-thomas
